# I cant figure out why my loop is not working correctly when i do execution it also prints the incorrect option cout

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int a,b,c,z,a1,b1,a2,b2; //decleration of variables
    float l;
    char opt;
    for(;;)
    {
    cout << "-----Calculator----- " <<endl <<endl;
    cout << "Press (a) to add two vectors \n";
    cout << "Press (s) to subtract two vectors \n";
    cout << "Press (m) to multiply two vectors \n";
    cout << "Press (l) to calculate the length of two vectors \n";
    cout << "Press (q) to quit \n"<<endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: \t";
    cin>>opt;


//INPUT FOR ADDITION
        for(;opt == 'a';)
        {

        cout<<"Enter first number of vactor"<<endl;
        cin>>a1;
        cout<<"Enter second number of vactor"<<endl;
        cin>>a2;
        cout<< "The vactor is"<<" :"<<"["<<a1<<","<<a2<<"]"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        cout<<"enter the first number of vactor 2"<<endl;
        cin>>b1;
        cout<<"Enter the second number of vactor 2"<<endl;
        cin>>b2;
        //-------------------------------//
        a=a1+b1;     // Adding copmonent1 of 1st vector with component1 of 2nd vector
        b=a2+b2;     // Adding copmonent2 of 1st vector with component1 of 2nd vector    
        cout<<"The sum is"<<"["<<a<<","<<b<<"]"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press any key to cont.... \n ";
        //-------------------------------//
        getch ();
        break;
        }

//INPUT FOR SUBTRACTION
        for(;opt=='s';)
        {

        cout << "Enter 1st component of vector \n";
        cin>>a1;
        cout << "Enter 2nd component of vector \n";
        cin>>a2;
        cout << "The vector is \t : \t "<<"["<<a1<<","<<a2<<"]"<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        cout << "Enter 1st component of vector \n";
        cin>>b1;
        cout << "Enter 2nd component of vector \n";
        cin>>b2;
        cout << "The vector is \t : \t "<<"["<<b1<<","<<b2<<"]"<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        a=a1-b1;  // Subtracting copmonent1 of 1st vector with component1 of 2nd vector
        b=a2-b2;  // Subtracting copmonent2 of 1st vector with component1 of 2nd vector
        cout << "The difference is \t : \t " <<"["<<a<<","<<b<<"]"<<endl;
        cout<<"Press any key to cont.... \n ";
        //-------------------------------//
        getch ();
        break;
        }

// INPUT FOR Multiply CALCULATION
        for(;opt=='m';)
        {

        cout << "Enter 1st component of vector \n";
        cin>>a1;
        cout << "Enter 2nd component of vector \n";
        cin>>a2;
        cout << "The vector is \t : \t "<<"["<<a1<<","<<a2<<"]"<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        cout << "Enter 1st component of vector \n";
        cin>>b1;
        cout << "Enter 2nd component of vector \n";
        cin>>b2;
        cout << "The vector is \t : \t "<<"["<<b1<<","<<b2<<"]"<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        a=a1*b1;  //Multiplying copmonent1 of 1st vector with component1 of 2nd vector
        b=a2*b2;  // Multiplying copmonent2 of 1st vector with component2 of 2nd vector
        c=(a1*b1)+(a2*b2); // by formula of dot product used for vectors adding adding two products
        cout<<"The multiplication is \t : \t " <<c<<endl;
        cout<<"Press any key to cont.... \n ";
        //-------------------------------//
        getch ();
        break;
        }

// INPUT FOR LENGHTH CALCULATION
        for(;opt=='l';)
        {

        cout << "Enter 1st component of vector \n";
        cin>>a1;
        cout << "Enter 2nd component of vector \n";
        cin>>a2;
        cout << "The vector is \t : \t "<<"["<<a1<<","<<a2<<"]"<<endl;
        //-------------------------------//
        // As the formula for length is sqrt(square of component 1 + square of component 2)
        a=a1*a1; // Taking square of component 1
        b=a2*a2; // Taking square of component 2
        l=sqrt(a+b);    //taking square root of (a+b) // Taking square root of result
        cout<<"The length is \t : \t " <<l<<endl;
        cout<<"Press any key to cont.... \n ";
        //-------------------------------//
        getch ();
        break;
        }
//      Quit
        for(;opt=='q';)
        {
        cout <<"Press any key to QUIT" << endl;
        getch ();
        return 0;
        //-------------------------------//
        }
        //INCORRECT OPTION
        cout<<"The option is incorrect. PLEASE enter the correct option";
        cout<<endl;
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please.

Comment: We don't know what you're asking for help with when you essentially say "This isn't doing what I want fix it plz kkthxbai"

Comment: Explain what is wrong with your program. How is the output wrong?

Comment: output is correct but when any calculation is out it also prints wrong key enters option at the end

Comment: This is not surprising - there is no condition around this output, what did you expect?

Comment: You might be interested in looking up what a `switch` statement is. And it may be a good idea to handle the opptions in separate functions to keep your menu-logic and business-logic apart.

Comment: I personally use a completely separate function for printing even menus. I don't like doing anything but setup, initialization, and clean-up in main(). But what @Hulk suggested would be a good start.

Comment: Man you really need to use switch.
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Comment: my teacher made a condition to do it that way so im stuck with it
swith is good but i cant allow to use that i use the condition in incorrect option but it makes some other problems hulk send me the condition u r saying above

Comment: @user3073283 Your teacher is an idiot

Answer (score 2):

Your code is structured wrongly, you are using for loops for something they are not designed for.

Use a switch statement inside a do ... while loop and a boolean variable that tells you when to quit. Like this

```
bool quit = false;
do
{
    // menu code
    cin>>opt;
    switch (opt)
    {
    case 'a':
        // adding code
        break;
    case 's':
        // substracting code
        break;
    ...
    case 'q':
        quit = true;
        break;
    default:
        cout<<"The option is incorrect. PLEASE enter the correct option";
        cout<<endl;
        break;
    }
} while (!quit);
out <<"Press any key to QUIT" << endl;
getch ();
return 0;
```

You should understand that certain C++ contructs are designed for certain situations. A switch statement is designed for when you have a choice between multiple alternatives, that's what your program needs so that's what you should use. A for loop is designed mainly for when you want to repleat something a fixed number of times, that's **not** what your program needs so you shouldn't use a for loop. A do ... while loop is designed for situations when you want to loop a varying number of times (but at least once). That's exactly what your program needs so you should use a do ... while loop.

**EDIT**

Apparently you are not allowed to use a switch statement. Here's the above code using if ... else if ... else instead of switch

```
bool quit = false;
do
{
    // menu code
    cin>>opt;
    if (opt == 'a')
    {
        // adding code
    }
    else if (opt == 's')
    {
        // substracting code
    }
    ...
    else if (opt == 'q')
    {
        quit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The option is incorrect. PLEASE enter the correct option";
        cout<<endl;
    }
} while (!quit);
out <<"Press any key to QUIT" << endl;
getch ();
return 0;
```

Comment: actually i have to do that program with both of them i correct it in do while but stuck with for loop

Comment: @user3073283 Well I think your mistake was to use one for loop for each option when you should have used one for loop for the whole program. Replace the do while loop with a for loop and it should work. `bool quit = false; for (;!quit;) { ... }`